# Django - How do I render a parent object in template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I need to display some product's supplier, next to {{product.description}} but I can't get it to show on my table.

models.py

```
class Supplier(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Product(models.Model):
sku = models.IntegerField(null=True)
description = models.CharField(max_length=30)
costprice = models.FloatField(null=True, max_length=99, blank=True)
retailprice = models.FloatField(null=True, max_length=99, blank=True)
barcode = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=99, unique=True)
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.description
```

views.py

```
def products(request):
products = Product.objects.all()
suppliers = Supplier.objects.all()
context = {'products': products,
           'suppliers': suppliers}
return render(request, 'crmapp/products.html', context)
```

products.html

```
<tr>
{% for product in products %}
  <td>{{product.id}}</td>
  <td><h6><strong>{{product.description}}</strong></h6></td>
  <td >{{products.supplier}}</td>
  <td>£{{product.costprice |floatformat:2}}</td>
  <td>£{{product.retailprice |floatformat:2}}</td>
  <td>{{product.barcode}}</td>
  
</tr>
```

{% endfor %}

Comment: Are you passing in a description? Can you fix your indentation as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling mistake, I think.

```
 <td >{{products.supplier}}</td>
```

Must be:

```
 <td >{{product.supplier}}</td>
```

Notice I've removed the `s` in product**s**.

---

Also, you don't need this in your views.py:

```
suppliers = Supplier.objects.all()
```

`{{product.supplier}}` will trigger a query to the db. To avoid that, use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

```
products = Product.objects.all().prefetch_related('supplier')
```

Note that this is optional. It will just improve efficency, but merely fixing the spelling mistake answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! That did it! :D